# The value for a object inside a viewmodel lost on redirect to action in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, redirecttoaction

I have a view model -

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public int id{get;set;};
   Public SomeClass obj{get;set;};
}
public class SomeClass
{
   public int phone{get;set;};
   public int zip{get;set;};
}
```

So on my controller when I post back MyViewModel it has all the values for all the fields...but when I do

```
return RedirectoAction("SomeAction",vm);//where vm->MyViewModel object that has all values...
```

it loses the values for SomeClass object?...can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The second argument to `RedirectToAction` is route values, not a view model.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291.aspx)

So if you do:

```
return RedirectoAction("SomeAction", new {Foo = "Bar"});
```

Then, with the default model binding, you'll redirect to this URI:

```
http://site/ControllerName/SomeAction?Foo=Bar
```

Remember how a redirect works over the wire. You *can't* pass a model. You can *only* change the URI.

Comment: hmm..so in this example i tried doing-........ 
return RedirectoAction("SomeAction",new {vm=vm}) and also.......
return RedirectoAction("SomeAction",new MyViewModel{idvm.id,obj= new SomeClass {phone=vm.phone,zip=vm.zip} ) but didnt work ?

Comment: I'm going to say this again, slowly: The second argument to `RedirectToAction` **is not a view model.** It changes the URI. **That is all.**

Comment: got it...you could have said "tempdata" slowly..:)

Comment: OR If you can bypass the action.. return View("SomeView", vm) ... which will pass the viewmodel.